# Getting modification time in perl on my MAC not working

Tags: macos, perl, stat, ctime

I have following code that I am using to get modification time of a file. But it is not working. Whether I use stat command or -M operator, I am getting error messages like "Use of uninitialized value…" or "Can't call method "mtime" on an undefined value" depending on which method I use. Any suggestions? I am using MAC OS v10.8.5. I swear that the -M option worked yesterday few times but since then it has stopped working. I am flummoxed.

```
<code>
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use Time::localtime;
use File::stat;
use warnings;

$CosMovFolder = '/Logs/Movies';
#sorting files based on modification date
opendir (DIR, $CosMovFolder);
@moviedir=readdir(DIR);
#$file1modtime = -M $moviedir[1]; #it works here but doesn't work if used after the 
sort line below. Why?

closedir(DIR);  
#sorting files by modification dates
@moviedir = sort { -M "$CosMovFolder/$a" <=> -M "$CosMovFolder/$b" } (@moviedir); 
#$file1modtime = -M $moviedir[1]; #tried this, not working.  same uninitialized value error message

$latestfile = $moviedir[1];
print "file is: $latestfile\n";
open (FH,$latestfile);

#$diff_mins = (stat($latestfile))[9];  #didn't work, same uninitialized value error message
my $diff_mins = (stat(FH)->mtime); # Can't call method "mtime" on an undefined value error message
print $diff_mins,"\n";
close FH
</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) at the beginning of your script.  You'll find that there's a problem with the way you're calling [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).  Unless you need to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file for some other reason, don't.  Skip the whole FH stuff.

But, your bigger problem is you're trying to `stat` a file but you're not giving the full path to the file.  [`chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) to the folder (or pass the full path to `stat`).

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;

my $CosMovFolder = '/Logs/Movies';
chdir($CosMovFolder) or die $!;
#sorting files based on modification date
opendir (DIR, $CosMovFolder);
#Grab all items that don't start with a period.
my @moviedir = grep(/^[^\.]/, readdir(DIR));
#$file1modtime = -M $dir[1]; # tried this, not working.  same uninitialized value error message
closedir(DIR);  
@moviedir = sort { -M "$CosMovFolder/$a" <=> -M "$CosMovFolder/$b" } (@moviedir); #sorting files by modification dates
my $latestfile = $moviedir[0];
print "file is: $latestfile\n";
print localtime(stat($latestfile)->mtime) . "\n";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Jim. I didn't notice that i was not passing the full path to the file. Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: No problem.  Done it a hundred times too.  Don't forget to "Accept" the answer if you're happy with it.